# What am I doing wrong in my script?

Tags: arrays, bash

I wrote this script that is suppose to read a file line by line and then do a while loop and set the output as an array, but for some reason my script doesn't wait for user input before it continues, it automatically choses 0.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

declare -a ArrayBox


filename="text.txt"
exec 10<&0

exec < $filename

x=0
while read line
do
    ArrayBox[$x]=$line
    echo "[$x] $line"
    let x++

    if [[ $x -eq 5 ]]
    then

        echo  "Enter your chose: "; read num; 
        echo "you chose ${ArrayBox[$num]}"

    fi


done


#Output
[0] as
[1] ag
[2] sd
[3] gh
[4] tr
Enter your chose: 
you chose as
[5] fg
[6] fg
```

Comment: You're trying to read from stdin but you did an exec to make stdin come from a file, not the terminal

Comment: is there a different way to read a file

Comment: There isn't a need to use a loop to assign values to the array. A single line will work `IFS=$'\n' ArrayBox=($(<text.txt))`. What your script seems to be doing is already provided by shell builtin `select`.

Comment: @alvits this is an antipattern: it's broken because of pathname expansion. And it messes up `IFS`. Use `mapfile` for this instead (or just a plain `while` loop).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf - I totally agree with you. However, in the OP's case, the text file does not contain wildcards that will get subjected to pathname expansion. I don't see why it will mess up `IFS` when it's not permanently changed. `mapfile` is good, unfortunately it doesn't exist in all versions of `bash`. Your suggestion is good.

Comment: @alvits How do you know OP will not want to use it with glob characters? Also, `IFS` _is_ permanently changed: with several assignments in a row, e.g., `IFS=abc stuff=thing` all the assignments are performed. (and not, as it's sometimes thought, that the first assignment is understood as an environmental assignment; that doesn't make sense as there are no commands executed).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf - I won't try to convince you that `var=value anothervar=anothervalue` won't set `var` to `value` after the line is executed. Maybe there are shells that does exactly what you say. In my `bash` the `value` is never assigned to `var`. However, you are right that I don't know if the OP intends to put wildcard in the text file.

Comment: @alvits: have you even tried it? `var=value anothervar=anothervalue; echo "$var"`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf - yes I have. And it didn't behave like you described. On both `GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)` and `GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15)`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf - I stand corrected. On `GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15)` it behaved like you described.

Comment: @alvits: it behaves like that in every POSIX shell (and it's sensible: there's really no reason whatsoever to invoke an assignment with a special environment variable).

Answer (score 2):

You are duplicating `stdin` fd number 0 to 10 and setting stdin to file. So all further inputs for `read` (both for `while` and `num`) are meant to come from the file. Since you don't intend to provide data for the 2nd `read` via file, it takes the default value which you have set earlier i.e 0. In this case you need to explicitly tell `read` to read from stdin (the duplicated fd which you had made earlier i.e fd `10`)

from `help read` here is the way:

> -u fd     read from file descriptor FD instead of the standard input

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a array=()
declare -i x=0

exec 10<&0
exec < "input_file.txt"

while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]
do
    array+=("$line")
    echo "[$x] $line"
    x=$((x+1))

    if [[ $x -eq 5 ]]
    then
        echo 'Enter your choice: '
        read -u 10 choice
        echo "You chose: ${array[$choice]}";
    fi
done
```

And here is the output:

```
$ cat -n input_file.txt 
     1  line1
     2  line2 abcd
     3  line3 abc
     4  line4 ab
     5  line5 a
     6  line6 
     7  line7
$ ./script.bash 
[0] line1
[1] line2 abcd
[2] line3 abc
[3] line4 ab
[4] line5 a
Enter your choice: 
3
You chose: line4 ab
[5] line6 
[6] line7
$
```

Edit: as Huihoo pointed out you can use `read -u 10 num` or `read num <&10` to read from fd 10. Thanks Huihoo

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` to read specific line from file (first line number is 1, not 0). An example:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
declare -a ArrayBox
filename="text.txt"
x=1
while true
do  
    line=`sed "${x}q;d" ${filename}`
    ArrayBox[$x]=$line
    echo "[$x] $line"
    let x++

    if [[ $x -eq 6 ]]
    then

        echo  "Enter your chose: "; read num; 
        echo "you chose ${ArrayBox[$num]}"
        break

    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `read num` with `read -u 10 num` or `read num <&10`, both work.